# implementing Map<string, List>

Tags: java, groovy

I need to implement Map as normal hashmap is not allowing multiple key-value pairs.

```
def createRecommendationMap(List recommendation, Map recommendationMap)
    {
          if(!(allMaps.containsKey(RECOMMENDATION_MAP))) 
         {

             recommendation.each{record ->
                def javaRecord = KdTypeUtil.convertRecordFromKDTypes(record)
                def key = // returns just a string
                                       recommendationMap.put(key, javaRecord)
              }

             allMaps.put(RECOMMENDATION_MAP, recommendationMap)
         }
         return recommendationMap;
    }
```

what did I miss here ?

I am expecting a size of 9, but getting only a size of 8(duplicate key values are deleted)

I am expecting both of the below key-value pairs, but the second one is being deleted

> "NONMEDIAOUTBOUND24.0P10":["CHANNEL":"OUTBOUND", "STOCK_LEVEL":0.0,
>   "PRODUCT_ID":"SAM-STD-I9100W-1",
>   "OFFER_ID":"FBUN-MVP-VME-VIRGIN-29-12-05", "P_BAND":"P10",
>   "CONTRACT_LENGTH":24.0, "INCENTIVE_POINTS":15.0,
>   "CUST_TYPE":"NONMEDIA"],
>
> "NONMEDIAOUTBOUND24.0P10":["CHANNEL":"OUTBOUND", "STOCK_LEVEL":0.0,
>   "PRODUCT_ID":"LGE-STD-E960-1",
>   "OFFER_ID":"FBUN-MVP-VME-VIRGIN-29-12-05", "P_BAND":"P10",
>   "CONTRACT_LENGTH":24.0, "INCENTIVE_POINTS":10.0,
>   "CUST_TYPE":"NONMEDIA"],

Comment: What's `allMaps`?  Can you supply some input data, and the expected result?

Comment: Hi Tim, edited the question with example

Comment: Do you have some example input? Also, what is `allMaps`?

Comment: Hi Tim, the values(channel, stock_level, etc) are coming from DB and for a customer(if he is in a particular values zone)I need to pull the values. for the values channel = OUTBOUND, custType = NONMEDIA, contractLength = 24.0 and pBand = P10, there are two values associated, but as I used map, the second value is deleted from the map...If I cant do that in my coding, will try to include apache commons jar and chck it.

Comment: Added a possible solution...  Hard to say without extra info, but I *think* it's right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you can replace all your code with:

```
Map createRecommendationMap( List recommendation ) {
    println 'inside createRecommendationMap of Maps **************** '
    //If not already created, create the map.  Stick to KD types, not many
    //fields required.
    //Keyed on Tariff type desc, commitment duration, p_band.
    if( !allMaps.containsKey(RECOMMENDATION_MAP) ) {
        allMaps[ RECOMMENDATION_MAP ] = recommendation.inject( [:] ) { map, r ->
            def k = "${r.CUST_TYPE}${r.CHANNEL}${r.CONTRACT_LENGTH}${r.P_BAND}".toString()
            def m = map[ k ]
            if( !m ) {
                m = []
                map[ k ] = m
            }
            m << r
            map
        }
    }
    allMaps[ RECOMMENDATION_MAP ]
}
```

My full test-app which runs in Groovy 1.5.6 is:

```
class Test {

    Map allMaps = [:]
    String RECOMMENDATION_MAP = 'SOME_KEY'

    Map createRecommendationMap( List recommendation ) {
        println 'inside createRecommendationMap of Maps **************** '
        //If not already created, create the map.  Stick to KD types, not many
        //fields required.
        //Keyed on Tariff type desc, commitment duration, p_band.
        if( !allMaps.containsKey(RECOMMENDATION_MAP) ) {
            allMaps[ RECOMMENDATION_MAP ] = recommendation.inject( [:] ) { map, r ->
                def k = "${r.CUST_TYPE}${r.CHANNEL}${r.CONTRACT_LENGTH}${r.P_BAND}".toString()
                def m = map[ k ]
                if( !m ) {
                    m = []
                    map[ k ] = m
                }
                m << r
                map
            }
        }
        allMaps[ RECOMMENDATION_MAP ]
    }
}

def recommendation = [ ["CHANNEL":"OUTBOUND", "STOCK_LEVEL":0.0, "PRODUCT_ID":"SAM-STD-I9100W-1", "OFFER_ID":"FBUN-MVP-VME-VIRGIN-29-12-05", "P_BAND":"P10", "CONTRACT_LENGTH":24.0, "INCENTIVE_POINTS":15.0, "CUST_TYPE":"NONMEDIA"],
                       ["CHANNEL":"OUTBOUND", "STOCK_LEVEL":0.0, "PRODUCT_ID":"LGE-STD-E960-1", "OFFER_ID":"FBUN-MVP-VME-VIRGIN-29-12-05", "P_BAND":"P10", "CONTRACT_LENGTH":24.0, "INCENTIVE_POINTS":10.0, "CUST_TYPE":"NONMEDIA"] ]

def recommendationMap = new Test().createRecommendationMap( recommendation ) 
recommendationMap.each { key, value ->
    println key
    value.each { println "    $it" }
}
```

That prints:

```
NONMEDIAOUTBOUND24.0P10
    ["CHANNEL":"OUTBOUND", "STOCK_LEVEL":0.0, "PRODUCT_ID":"SAM-STD-I9100W-1", "OFFER_ID":"FBUN-MVP-VME-VIRGIN-29-12-05", "P_BAND":"P10", "CONTRACT_LENGTH":24.0, "INCENTIVE_POINTS":15.0, "CUST_TYPE":"NONMEDIA"]
    ["CHANNEL":"OUTBOUND", "STOCK_LEVEL":0.0, "PRODUCT_ID":"LGE-STD-E960-1", "OFFER_ID":"FBUN-MVP-VME-VIRGIN-29-12-05", "P_BAND":"P10", "CONTRACT_LENGTH":24.0, "INCENTIVE_POINTS":10.0, "CUST_TYPE":"NONMEDIA"]
```

Comment: Hi Tim, hope this works with 1.5.6 version of GDk...same old limitation :-)

Comment: I've checked, and I *think* it's ok... `Map.withDefault` says it's been around since 1.0 and so has `inject` ;-)

Comment: my allMaps declaration is def allMaps = [:]

Comment: let me try and get back to you

Comment: @Techie fingers crossed... ;-)

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.withDefault() is applicable for argument types:

Comment: @Techie right...try that we have to go the long way round :-(

Comment: m is returned as null, java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'NONMEDIAOUTBOUND24P10' on null object

Comment: @Techie Which line? Hang on... Installing Groovy 1.5.6 (*sigh* ;-))

Comment: at m, the logs are inside createRecommendationMap of Maps ****************                                                  k : NONMEDIAOUTBOUND24.0P10                                      m : null                                                         map : ["NONMEDIAOUTBOUND24P10":[["CHANNEL":OUTBOUND, "STOCK_LEVEL":1137.0, "PRODUCT_ID":LGE-STD-E960-1, "OFFER_ID":FBUN-MVP-VME-VIRGIN-29-12-05, "P_BAND":P10, "CONTRACT_LENGTH":24.0, "INCENTIVE_POINTS":10.0, "CUST_TYPE":NONMEDIA]]] k : NONMEDIAOUTBOUND24.0P10

Comment: @Techie Downloaded Groovy 1.5.6. Pasted that code in (wrapped in a quick Test class). Runs fine.

Comment: @Techie added my complete test script to the answer above.  Can you give that a go?

Comment: my mistake...looks good now...Thanks a Ton Tim, you are a star...will trouble you with few more questions...when needed...cheers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're reimplementing a MultiMap. Both [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html) and [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) have widely-used and thoroughly tested implementations of this.